# Formula field needs to determine where today is in an opportunity's period of performance (PoP)

Tags: case, if

Not worrying about leap years, I need an if/case statement for:
if (today() < start_date__c+364), then PoP_location__c='Base year'

if ((today() >= start_date__c+365) and (today() < start_date__c+729)), then PoP_location__c='Option Year 1', etc. for multiple option years

Answer (score 2):

It could be as simple as:

```
IF(TODAY() < Start_Date__c + 364, 
  "Base Year", "Option Year " & TEXT(FLOOR((TODAY()-Start_Date__c)/365))
)
```

We use the fact that subtracting two days returns a number, which we then divide by 365 and discard the fraction using FLOOR.